# Excel filter by two criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large data set (more than 1,000 items) scoring the relationship between two items. Something like:

```
----------------------------
| item1  | item2   | score |
|--------------------------|
| apple  | orange  | 1     |
| apple  | banana  | 5     |
| apple  | lemon   | 3     |
| banana | apple   | 2     |
| lemon  | orange  | 3     |
| lemon  | apple   | 1     |
| ...etc.|         |       |
----------------------------
```

I need to find the smallest score for each item1 and sort them like:

```
-----------------------------
| item1  | item2    | score |
|---------------------------|
| apple  | orange   | 1     |
| banana | apple    | 2     |
| lemon  | apple    | 1     |
-----------------------------
```

I can use filter to find the smallest one by one, but it is a massive task to find them for each. I know advanced filter should be able to solve this easily, but have not been able to find the way. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Lemon, apple is 1 in your first sample. Why is it 2 in the second?

Comment: @teylyn my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what pivot tables can do without formulas and just a few clicks.

Click in the source data and then Insert > Pivot Table. From the Field List, drag Item1 into the rows area, drag Score into the Values area, then right-click "Sum of Scores" and change "Value Field Settings" to "minimum".

[image]

You can sort the pivot table by the values of the score, too.